# How to Show Profile Pictures to their Corresponding contact record

Tags: apex, image-formula

I want to display Contact User Picture In Page Layout. How Can I call Image Id automatically in Contact formula.

I tried this logic but its only works for one record.

```
IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01528000003vB2","",300,300)
```

But I want call automatically all image as per the record name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a formula create a text field to store the file id on the record and then reference that text field in your formula to automatically display the image you want to show. This gets your formula to be dynamic for every record.

```
IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" & Image_Id__c & "","",300,300)
```

If you don't want to do that I suggest creating a vf page that you can drop into the layout. With a controller you can then query for the image you want and then display it. It also gives you the ability to display more than one image if that's what you need as compared to the formula where it would be one at a time.